# can't install atom editor on arch linux

Tags: linux, atom-editor, archlinux

package `re2-20170101-1` is not installing.

i have also marked extra as siglevel never because before it was giving signature error

```
error: re2: signature from "Anatol Pomozov <anatol.pomozov@gmail.com>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/re2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
```

then i marked extra as siglevel never

```
[extra]
SigLevel = Never
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

so i get this error.(404 error was also before adding signlevel = Never)

```
[pi@vision pacman.d]$ sudo pacman -S atom
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) apm-1.18.1-1  electron-1.4.16-2  minizip-1:1.2.11-1
             re2-20170101-1  atom-1.16.0-1

Total Download Size:     0.15 MiB
Total Installed Size:  217.06 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.f4st.host : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.cicku.me : Failed to connect to mirrors.cicku.me port 80: Connection refused
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.nluug.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.myrveln.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.hactar.xyz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.dynamict.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.ba : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.tyborek.pl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.uni-plovdiv.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.neuf.no : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.archlinux.no : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.js-webcoding.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.n-ix.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.de.leaseweb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.gnomus.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.dotsrc.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirrors.uk2.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.aur.rocks : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.acc.umu.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.23media.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror5.bastelfreak.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from gluttony.sin.cvut.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.datacenter.by : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.rnl.tecnico.ulisboa.pt : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.kaminski.io : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.snt.utwente.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.manchester.m247.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.cinosure.com : The requested URL returned error: 403
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.niyawe.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.byfly.by : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.lug.mtu.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.kangaroot.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nl.leaseweb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.rit.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.fluxent.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.netcologne.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.united-gameserver.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.wa.co.za : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.midov.pl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.is.co.za : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.surlyjake.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.wearetriple.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.vi-di.fr : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from foss.aueb.gr : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.swin.edu.au : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.openlabto.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.metalgamer.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.vfn-nrw.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archimonde.ts.si : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirrors.linux.ro : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.kernel.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from fooo.biz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.es.its.nyu.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www.gtlib.gatech.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.pseudoform.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.vpsfree.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.lysator.liu.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.polymorf.fr : The requested URL returned error: 404
 re2-20170101-1-x86_64   1190.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
(5/5) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(5/5) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/re2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (checksum)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
```

Comment: what is your kernel version ?
and try to update packages db before: "pacman -Sy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Pacman said, the key is corrupted:

> error: re2: signature from "Anatol Pomozov "
>   is invalid :: File
>   /var/cache/pacman/pkg/re2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted
>   (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)). Do you want to delete
>   it? [Y/n] n

note: `SigLevel = Never` you should not avoid the check to staying safe.

Instead of that, You must refresh your keys list:

```
pacman-key --refresh-keys
```

If you never imported the whole archlinux keyring before, you should get it (before refresh):

```
pacman-key --populate archlinux
```

---

2. Finally, can see that pacman cannot find the archive.
   This occur often when the pkg revision has changed and outdated.
   (you could not see it before, cause of the PGP error)

> error: failed retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from
>   mirror.f4st.host : The requested URL returned error: 404 error: failed
>   retrieving file 're2-20170101-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from
>   mirrors.cicku.me : Failed to connect to mirrors.cicku.me port 80:
>   Connection refused

Let's refresh your repositories database :

```
sudo pacman -Sy
pacman -S atom
```